# Accessing C# variables through javascript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am implementing auto-complete on a search box using asp.NET and c#.
This is how i have divided my code:
I have a class class ListSuggestions.cs, the default Default.aspx.cs class and the default page Default.aspx where my jquery autocomplete code lies.

This is my ListSuggestions.cs:

```
public class ListSuggestions
{
    public string[] loadArray(string[] companiesArray)
    {          
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Name] FROM [Party_Company_General]", conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        var companies = new List<string>();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            companies.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
        }
        return companiesArray = companies.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Default.aspx.cs :

```
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private string[] companiesArray { set; get; }

    public class JavaScript
    {
        public static string Serialize(object o)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return js.Serialize(o);
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListSuggestions listSuggestions = new ListSuggestions();
        String[] companiesArray = listSuggestions.loadArray(this.companiesArray);
    }

}
```

Default.aspx script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {

          var availableTags = <%=JavaScript.Serialize(this.companiesArray) %>

          $(".searchbox").autocomplete({
              source: availableTags
          });
      });
  </script>
```

The problem is that i don't think the `companiesArray` string is being accessible to the JavaScript code.
What might be the problem with my code?
How can i solve my problem, someone help me out please.

Comment: @Mansfield i tried making it public earlier on but didnt work either.

Comment: Do you get any errors (if so, what are they)? When you view that javascript as it arrived in the browser, is that what you expected to see?

Comment: No errors, the problem is that i think that String[] companiesArray is local to the Page_Load method. I have tried declaring it after the partial class with some initial data and it works fine, the problem is that i cant call an object there using the this keyword.

Comment: What do you think line `return companiesArray = companies.ToArray();` does?

Comment: @Igor returning the array in a new variable called companiesArray

Comment: @MutieMule - you can only return "an array", you can't *name* that array or the variable it lands in.

Comment: @MutieMule - yes, you don't want that `listSuggestions.loadArray` to end up in (just) a local variable, you need to write it to that class-level field (which must be protected or public), before the aspx code can pick it up.

Comment: @HansKesting thank you for the help. Followed it and succeeded. First converted the list into an array and assigned it a name and then returned the name of that array. You can check my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. Thanks all who had helped me by giving their answers.
I changed my ListSuggestions.cs to:

```
public string[] loadArray(ref string[] companiesArray)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            //Fetch the field to auto complete from the database
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Name] FROM [Party_Company_General]", conn);
            //Open connection
            conn.Open();
            //Read data from the database
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //create a list of companies
            var companiesList = new List<string>();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                companiesList.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
            }
            //Convert list to an array
            companiesArray = companiesList.ToArray();

            //Return the array
            return companiesArray;
        }
```

Also, i changed the Default.aspx.cs code to:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        ListSuggestions listSuggestions;
        public string[] companiesArray;

        //A constructor
        public  Default()
        {
         listSuggestions= new ListSuggestions();
         companiesArray = listSuggestions.loadArray(ref companiesArray);
        }
        //Serializer
        public class JavaScript
        {
            public static string Serialize(object o)
            {
             JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
             return js.Serialize(o);
             }
          }
     }
```

I created a constructor and did away with the Page_Load method.

Lastly, i changed my script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {

          var availableTags = <%=JavaScript.Serialize(companiesArray) %>

          $(".searchbox").autocomplete({
              source: availableTags
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: You don't need that `ref companiesArray`, as you are returning it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The field must be declared public/protected for proper visibility from the ASPX markup. In any case, you could declare a property:

I prefer protected and Secondly use the property to store data.

First, Change

```
 private string[] companiesArray { set; get; }
```

To:

```
 public string[] companiesArray { set; get; }
```

Change,

```
String[] companiesArray = listSuggestions.loadArray(this.companiesArray);
```

To:

```
companiesArray = listSuggestions.loadArray(this.companiesArray);
```

Change

```
return companiesArray = companies.ToArray();
```

To

```
return companies.ToArray();
```

Comment: changed but still no difference, but for sure i know it is scope issues.

Comment: @Mutie Mule, Try once with public

Comment: Doesnt function too when using public.

Comment: @MutieMule - did you use all three changes? What if you debug the codebehind, do the correct values end up in the expected places?

Answer (score 1):

String[] companiesArray is local in scope to the Page_Load method.  Your Default.aspx code should be fine, but you are not actually loading anything into the class level companiesArray.

Comment: thats what i tend to understand because when i declare String[] companiesArray just after the public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page and instantiate it with some initial variables, it works fine. 
The problem is that i cant call an object there the way have called it in the Page_Load method. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
public String[] CompaniesArray {
    get {
        return this.companiesArray;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var availableTags = <%=JavaScript.Serialize(CompaniesArray)%>;

        $(".searchbox").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

Your array could still be private, but giving a public getter to be accessible by everyone. No risks that something will ever alterate the array from the outside of the class.

Comment: Now this leads to a Stackoverflow Exception error on the get. Any solution @Frederik

Comment: Please take a look at my last update. This should basically work. Then, fill your private variable in the `Page_Load` method. You may ensure that the private variable is correctly filled prior to any further operations. You may also consider the other answers that advise returning a value directly rather than an affection.

Comment: ...and I mean "affectation" :-)

Comment: thank you for the help, i changed my code and my declaration of the variables by passing the string by reference in a constructor. You can check my answer below.